# Getting Error on Checkout in any payment method

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment

Preconditions

```
Magento ver. 2.2.4
Developer mode/Production Mode
```

Expected result

```
User Should be able to pay after buying any product.
```

Actual result

```
On Any Payment Method i will get the following Error on placing an order

(An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.)
```

**UPDATE**:
In Exception Log :

```
 [2019-06-01 07:43:12] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_order_1` () VALUES () {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_order_1` () VALUES () at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sequence_order_1' doesn't exist at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

My env setting

```
db' => [
    'table_prefix' => 'sfgs_',
    'connection' => [
      'default' => [
        'host' => '',
        'dbname' => 'sfgs898',
        'username' => 'root',
        'active' => '1'
      ]
    ]
  ],
```

Comment: This is not actual error, check exception log and update the question

Comment: @SohelRana I added the log, please check.